# Is it possible to export a newsletter to PDF

Tags: export, mailing, pdf, newsletter

I have a newsletter that I have sent out to our contacts. I would like to export or save it as a PDF to post on our blog. I tried to copy the the HTML code into the blog, but the tables were not blog friendly. I am looking for 2 options
1) a way to remove the table formatting of the html code to then copy into a blog post
2) a way to export the newsletter that will preserve hyperlinks so that the PDF can be embedded in the web page.

Thank you

Comment: Could you say which CMS and version you are using, Drupal, Wordpress, Joomla etc and the version of CiviCRM?

Answer (score 7):

If you using CiviMail for sending newsletter than you can view the html snippet that was sent as a email body. To view the html you can go navigate to Mailings >> Scheduled and Send Mailing.

Find the mailing/newsletter name you want to convert into PDF and then click on **report** link besides the name. You will be redirected to CiviMail Report: [Name of Mailing] page.

Under **Content / Components** section you will see **View Complete Message** link. Open the link in new tab to see the content that was sent.

You can print this page using any one of the following method:

1. Use browser print option to Print as PDF
2. Use [wkhtmltopdf](https://wkhtmltopdf.org/) to print the page using the url

   `// example for drupal 7.
   // http://yoursite.com/civicrm/mailing/view?reset=1&id=1
   $ wkhtmltopdf content-url newsletter.pdf`
3. Use online tool to print pdf using url.
4. Use php to convert content of page into pdf.

**Note:** For #2 and #3 you will need to set **CiviMail: view public CiviMail content** permission for Anonymous user.

HTH

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I didn't answer this question. (I just edited it.)